# How do the distance spectra of imaginary and real roots of uniform tilings relate?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a tiling of the hyperbolic plane defined by a vertex configuration $\Gamma$.

Let in the following be $\Gamma = (3.4)^3$  to have a specific example at hand:

[image] [image]

Let the distance spectrum of  a "imaginary root" be the sequence of numbers $f(n)$ giving the numbers of vertices on the border of the following sequence $\mathcal{C}_n$ of graphs which are the vertices at some obvious distance $n$ away from the center of the graphs (which is not a vertex), i.e. the vertices on the $n$-th upright square around the center. The sequence starts with [$\langle 8, 28, 104,\dots \rangle$](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C28%2C104).

#### $\mathcal{C}_1$

[image]

#### $\mathcal{C}_2$

[image]

#### $\mathcal{C}_3$

[image]

Compare this spectrum with the distance spectrum of a "real root", i.e. an arbitrary vertex (arbitrary, because the tiling is vertex transitive). The sequence $g(n)$ of numbers of vertices at graph distance $n$ away from a real root starts with [$\langle 6, 21, 72 \dots \rangle$](http://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C21%2C72).

My question is:

> How do these two sequences relate? How can one be derived from the
> other?